# How to handle wordpress sso authentication with gatsby js?

Tags: javascript, front-end

I have a working wordpress setup with sso login, when user try to logged in he is redirected to another website to login and redirect back to the main site if successful.

I want to use gatsby js as front-end, so have to able to create login page which is redirected to  sso login site.

Have you any suggestion, how to handle this? i am new to gatsby and i have no idea.

Thank you.

Comment: How does this relate to Wordpress? What are you using for SSO in Wordpress?

Comment: Hi, thank for response, i use CAS as SSO.

Comment: The sso is working great, but i want to use gatsby as front login.

Comment: WordPress doesn't support SSO natively, so the solution would depend on whichever plugin you used to implement it, so you'll need to ask its developers.

Comment: Which bit exactly do you want to change? Do you mean you want a login form on your own site that will post directly to the SSO server? I'd guess the SSO server won't support that, as it would give your code a chance to steal the login credentials as they're passing through.